# Time needed to windows store process uploaded in app purchases?

Tags: windows, time, in-app-purchase, windows-store

what is the time needed for uploaded in app purchases for windows phone on windows store to be all set? I uploaded few of them 2 days ago and they are still not visible on my phone(and they should be, there is no issue in code).

---

For all of them status is **published** in windows store.

---

Is there any way I can check where is the issue? Can anyone provide me any info regarding this? I searched their web but there is nothing about time needed for processing.
Any info is helpful.
Thanks

Comment: If you need help with your account you can contact support via http://aka.ms/storesupport . Nobody else will be able to see your account status.

Answer (score 0):

It took about a day to upload in app purchases. It is necessary to reinstall the app on your test phone to make in app purchases visible.